# WPF Prism Why RegisterType? (with container)

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism, ioc-container

From my understanding, prism's unity container can resolve types event if they have not been registered, does this make _container.RegisterType kinda useless ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, what you are seeing is that Unity can (try to) make instances of classes directly, which is different from resolving types. It is perfectly reasonable to ask Unity to create a class "directly", however, in order to leverage "Inversion of Control", you would normally ask a container to resolve an interface, where you have mapped an interface to a class via `RegisterType`. This way you can map different implementations of classes to interfaces, without having to change your code, that is "Inversion of Control" and "Interfaced-based Programming" at work.

This process involves you asking to resolve an interface, followed by Prism finding what is bound to the interface i.e. resolution, and then making an instance for you i.e. factory capabilities. The factory capabilities of Unity will ensure that any other dependencies are resolved that are required to make an instance of the resolved class e.g. using dependency injection on class constructor parameters. This whole process is recursive until all dependencies are resolved.

**For Example**

If you ask for an `IFoo` and it is bound `Foo`, Unity will try and make an instance of `Foo`. If `Foo` has a constructor which takes an `IBar`, Unity will try and resolve `IBar` and create an instance of this to use in the constructor for `IFoo`.

So in the following code:

We can resolve `IFoo` as described above.

We can make an instance of class `Bar` directly, as it has no dependencies.

We can make an instance of class `Foo` directly, as it has a dependency on `IFoo`, but we have registered it.

We cannot make an instance of `Woo` directly as there is no registration for `IYay`.

```
//Types
public interface IBar{}
public class Bar : IBar {}

public interface IFoo{}
public class Foo : IFoo{ public Foo(IBar bar) {} }

public interface IYay{}
public class Woo { Woo(IYay yay){} }

//Registrations
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();
container.RegisterType<IBar, Bar>();

//Resolve IFoo
IFoo foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();

//Create Bar directly
Bar bar = container.Resolve<Bar>();

//Create Foo directly
Foo foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();

//Create Woo directly - won't work as IYay is not registered!
Yay yay = container.Reolve<Yay>();
```

In the example above `RegisterType` is used to map a concrete implementation to an interface. It is at this point that we can map any implementation we want and this will ripple throughout our program as long as the container is always used to resolve types.

For example, if we change what `IBar` is mapped to, then any time `IFoo` is resolved it will be created with that different implementation of `IBar`. This gives us a substantial way of altering a program's behaviour by just changing a single line of code i.e. `RegisterType`.

Comment: So .. if i don't have Interfaces for my view model, i can skip the register type (IoC) .. and directly call Resolve.. (so the container can inject my dependencies .. EventAggregator .. etc). ?

Comment: @Zapacila Correct. You can resolve against the class without it being registered, and Unity will create an instance and (try to) inject all your dependencies.

Comment: @Zapacila I have made a minor change to the example code. I made the constructor on `Foo` `public` as they are `private` if not explicitly  stated. Originally done from memory, now tested!